# Select MySQL rows from within 10 minutes

Tags: mysql

I'm storing data like this:

```
Time - Date
13:20:20 - 2015-03-13
```

I want to select MySQL entries from within 10 minutes. So if I execute it 13:00 it would be 12:50-13:00.

I've spent ages researching how to use the -interval x minutes, (now) function etc, it just doesn't work... It might be that I'm storing the data badly (varchar type) or timezones issues with server provider

I'm thinking something like `SELECT WHERE Time < - 60 seconds AND Date = '2015-03-13'`

But it just doesn't work. All help appreciated here.

Comment: `where (datetimefield > (now() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE))`. And yes, if you're using varchars for you dates, you're storing your dates HORRIBLY.

Comment: This does NOT work. I get the same amount of rows no matter if I change interval to 100 minutes or 10.000. A lot more info should show up.

Comment: yes, because your dates are varchars. mysql's probably converting them to incorrrect date/datetimes. your FIRST job is to redo your tables and use proper date/datetime types.

Comment: If it's possible, you should look into storing your dates as timestamp format as opposed to varchar.  It sounds like this is an already existing system, however, so I know this might not be a possibility (without tweaking a bunch of other things).

Comment: Oh, and consider consolidating into a **SINGLE** datetime field. keeping the dates and times separate will lead to wonky results when you're doing this calculation around midnight.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you "timestamps" aren't in a standard format either, so you can't really do much as far as casting to a datetime format easily either...

Answer (score 0):

***This is how you do it. Now don't do it.*** Seriously, have a look at how to do it below but go back and change the way you store dates to be a datetime type column. It makes your life easier and everyone who inherits the application from you (even if it's just a smarter you a year from now) won't hate you for making them do extra work.

```
create table mytmp
(
    mydate varchar(10),
    mytime varchar(8)
);

insert into mytmp
values ('2015-01-01', '01:23:45');
insert into mytmp
values ('2015-01-01', '01:24:45');
insert into mytmp
values ('2015-01-01', '01:25:45');


select *
from mytmp
where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(mydate, ' ', mytime), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S") > (now() - INTERVAL 10 minute);

select *
from mytmp
where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(mydate, ' ', mytime), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S") > (now() - INTERVAL 1 year);

drop table my tmp;
```

The key bit is to get the string date into a datetime format first using STR_TO_DATE. STR_TO_DATE needs a set format so that it can interpret what parts of the string represent what parts of a datetime type (minutes, days, years, etc) so you need to specify a format string. I used the CONCAT function to join your date and time columns into one string to do this. Now the INTERVAL operations will work as you're comparing like or compatible types.

You can find format strings for MySQL here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Edit: The format string you want is '%H:%i:%s - %Y-%m-%d' by the looks.

Comment: I should also add that if you can't change the application to use a proper column then you might want to consider creating a view which uses STR_TO_DATE to calculate a proper datetime column for read operations not related to the legacy application.